# any button on numeric key pad in vim counts as insert?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

With or without Num Lock, any time I do / and then enter in a number via the numeric key pad I go into insert mode (as though I hit <kbd>i</kbd>). If I type in numbers with the set of numbers above the letters on the keyboard it works as I'd expect and I can do stuff like /123.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, not getting the same behaviour here... could you post what version of vim you're using (you can check from within vim with `:version`), and also your `.vimrc`?

Comment: Vi IMproved 7.2. I don't have a ~/.vimrc file I have a ~/.viminfo but not a .vimrc.

Comment: Is this with a laptop's built-in keyboard? If so, maybe test it with an external USB keyboard and see if you get the same behaviour... I know that some laptop keyboards can behave weirdly sometimes.

Comment: It is indeed a laptop's built-in keyboard. I don't have access to a stand-alone keyboard atm but when I do I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

See `:help keycodes`.  The numbers on the keypad are probably mappable using `<k0>` through `<k9>`.  You can check this by using CTRL-K in Insert or Ex mode and then hitting the key in question.  In Insert mode, you can also use CTRL-V before hitting a key in order to check the character code that vim receives.  (This is likely to make a difference if you are using vim in a terminal, less likely if you are using gvim.)

Once you know how vim sees the key, you can check for a mapping with

```
:map <k9>
```

for example.

In the comments, you mention that you do not have a vimrc file.  That probably means you are running vim in compatible mode (i.e., the `'compatible'` option is set.)  This is not recommended, unless you are a fan of the original vi.  It might be worth trying

```
:set nocp
```

and see if that makes any difference.